# There are finitely many $k$-algebra morphisms from a $k$-algebra $A$ to $\overline{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $k$-algebra which is finite-dimensional as a vector space. I want to show that the set of homomorphisms from $A$ to the algebraic closure of $k$ (which we denote $\overline{k}$) is finite.

I know that if $a\in A$ then there are $e_i\in k$ such that $a^n+a^{n-1}e_{n-1}+...+e_0=0$.
If $f:A \rightarrow \overline{k}$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, we have $f(0)=0$.
And so $f(a^n)+e_{n-1}f(a^{n-1})+..+e_0f(1)=0$.

I don't see how to make use of $\overline{k}$ being algebraically closed.

Comment: The assumption that $\overline{k}$ is algebraically closed is irrelevant.  All that matters is that it is a domain.

Comment: Since it is a domain we have $f(a^n)+e_{n-1}f(a^{n-1})+..+e_0f(1)=f(a)^n+..+e_0f(1)$. I'm not sure where to go from here? I suspect that the size of the Hom set is going to be the dimension of $A$ as a vector space, and the that a $k$-algebra morphism is defined by why it does on the basis of $A$ but I don't see where it goes

Comment: You meant $f(a)^n+e_{n-1}f(a)^{n-1}+..+e_0=0$.

Comment: The given polynomial has finitely many roots, so there are finite choices for each generating element.

Comment: @Berci which polynomial, the one we get by replacing $f(a)$ with $x$? Then we also use that $A$ as a finite number of generating elements

Comment: Sure $f(a)$ is one of the finitely many roots, then repeat with the finitely many other elements of a $k$-basis of $A$.